# Error Code: 1005 can't create table

Tags: mysql

please see my create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE INTERNAL_MEDICINE_DETAIL(DIAGNOSE_ITEM VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
EXM_RESULT VARCHAR(50),
IDENTIFY_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
SUMMARY_ID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(SUMMARY_ID) REFERENCES INTERNAL_MEDICINE_SUMMARY(SUMMARY_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(DIAGNOSE_ITEM) REFERENCES INTERNAL_MEDICINE_ITEM_DEF(DIAGNOSE_ITEM))
```

The referenced two tables are created successfully:

```
CREATE TABLE INTERNAL_MEDICINE_ITEM_DEF(DIAGNOSE_ITEM VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ITEM_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
IDENTIFY_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE INTERNAL_MEDICINE_SUMMARY(SUMMARY_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
SUMMARY VARCHAR(1000),
R_IDENTIFYID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(R_IDENTIFYID) REFERENCES BASICINFO(IDENTIFY_ID))
```

I have seen the mean of error code 1005 on MySQL web site, it says:
Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table.

my error is 150 currently, but I cannot find the difference of the two foreign keys defined in INTERNAL_MEDICINE_DETAIL table with the two fields defined in INTERNAL_MEDICINE_SUMMARY  AND INTERNAL_MEDICINE_ITEM_DEF respectively.

So, could you please help me and tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

From the InnoDB [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) documentation:

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.

You'll need to create an index on `INTERNAL_MEDICINE_ITEM_DEF` that has `DIAGNOSE_ITEM` as its first column. (No need to change anything for `INTERNAL_MEDICINE_SUMMARY` since the referenced column is that table's primary key.)

Comment: Don't know why someone voted this down.. creating the index on the referenced table worked for me.